# Chrome extension: get referer tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How can i know if a tab is opened from a link or content-script on another tab's page?
And if i can i also need that tab's info.

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(id, info, tab){
      //  tab doesn't contain any such info
});
```

Comment: I'm afraid that for more info you need to inject a content script into that tab.

Comment: so i can't even get the tab id?

Answer (score 5):

You have a wrong format for your callback.

As per [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onCreated), the callback takes one [Tab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab) parameter and not three.

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab){
  // You now have things like tab.id exposed
  // If you have "tabs" permission, also things like tab.url

  // You also have tab.openerTabId for "referrer" tab

  // If you have host permissions for the tab:
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(
    tab.id,
    { code: "document.referrer;" },
    function(result) {
      // Here, you have the "real" referrer,
      // which would be empty for tabs opened via `chrome.tabs`
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: Excuse me for commenting on this old answer, but in my case it's very weird. Even when I create a new blank tab and enter something in it to search, the tab object passed to onUpdated has an openerTabId of the tab next to it on its left.

Comment: I wonder if opening a tab manually sets `openerTabId` to the tab that was active before you opened a new tab. Should be easy enough to test that theory.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes I guess that's exactly it, but do you mean it's normal? I think it sounds a lot like a bug and the documentation says nothing about this.

Comment: I can't find much information on crbug.com - I would suggest opening a ticket there.

Comment: Just so you know, I just tried a few more scenarios and it seems that the issue is a bit different, this only happens to the last tab (the rightmost one)! Manually opening a blank tab to the right of all tabs sets the openerTabId of the tab object passed to chrome.tabs.onUpdated to the id of the tab that was last active before opening this tab. I'm opening an issue right now. Thank you.